# Matching background-image URLs with regular expressions

Tags: javascript, css, regex

I'm trying to pull out absolute URLs from a block of CSS text and replace them with relative versions in JavaScript.

Here's what I have so far, which works great for URLs that don't have any parens in them:

```
var relativeCss = originalCss.replace(/url\(['|"]?(http[^\)|^'|^"]+)['|"]?\)/g, function(fullMatch, fullUrl) {
    var fileName = fullUrl.substr(fullUrl.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    return 'url("' + fileName + '")';
});
```

However, if there is a url with parenthesis as part of the file name, e.g. `background-image: url(http://uploads.server.com/IMG_0445 (2).jpg);`, then the greedy regex fails by stopping short on the first paren it finds.

Here's a simple test case: http://jsfiddle.net/NHfCg/1 for which the output should be:

```
.rule1 { background-image: url("image1.png"); } 
.rule2 { background-image: url("IMG_0445 (2).jpg"); }
```

I could write a longer regex that looks for specific file extensions to terminate on (e.g. `.(png|jpg|jpeg)['|"]?\)`, but wondering if there's a way to do this without having to whitelist extensions.

Some limitations I'm faced with:

1. I can't assume that the `background-image: url(...)` declaration will be properly terminated by a `;`
2. I can't assume that the `background-image: url(...)` will have the URL in quotes - it could be unquoted, can use single quotes (`'`), or double quotes (`"`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this pattern since you are sure that the url is always on a single line:

```
/\burl\s*\(\s*["']?([^"'\r\n,]+)["']?\s*\)/gi
```

Note that you can do this replacement in one shot like this:

```
var relativeCss = originalCss.replace(/\burl\s*\(\s*["']?http:\/\/((?:[^"'\r\n\/,]+)\/?)+["']?\s*\)/i, 'url("$1")');
```

Comment: That works great, thank you! I realize I can do it in one shot, but I need to do some extra processing with the matched group.

Comment: One additional change to account for multiple URL definitions on one line (since `background-image` supports multiple images) would be to add `\,` right after `\r\n`.

Comment: @VladMagdalin: indeed! I have forget this. To deal with this case you only need to forbid the `,` (since several `url(....)` are always separate with a `,`. I will edit my pattern to add the `,` in the character class.

Comment: This regexp doesn't match this patter:

url("images'/bg.'jpg")

that is a valid one for browsers. Do you know how to change your regexp in order to match this patter too?

Comment: @Fab: If you want to deal with this kind of thing you can simply use a non-capturing group and an alternation for each case and change `$1` to `$1$2` in the replacement string.

Comment: I did not get it, sorry, I'd like to use the regexp you put /\burl\s*\(\s*["']?([^"'\r\n,]+)["']?\s*\)/gi but I'd like to match this pattern too: url("images'/bg.'jpg")

Could you please make an example?

Thanks

Comment: @Fab: `var relativeCss = originalCss.replace(/\burl\s*\(\s*(?:'?http:\/\/((?:[^"'\r\n\/,]+)\/?)+'?|"http:\/\/((?:[^"\r\n\/,]+)\/?)+")\s*\)/i, 'url("$1$2")');`

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this

Find:

```
 #  /url\(\s*(["']?)\s*([^{}]*\.[a-zA-z]{2,3})\s*\1\s*\)/

 url
 \(

 \s* 
 ( ["']? )             # (1)
 \s* 
 (                     # (2 start)
      [^{}]*                # not {} so not to overrun
      \. [a-zA-z]{2,3}      # image file extension
                            # (comment this out if no file extension is possible)
 )                     # (2 end)
 \s* 
 \1                    # backref to grp 1
 \s* 

 \)
```

Replace:

```
 "url(" + transformed($2) + ")"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a regex which handles both a list of urls and commas in the urls.

```
/\burl\s*\(\s*["']?([^"'\r\n\)\(]+)["']?\s*\)/gi
```

Commas are allowed in urls and are used in dataURIs to separate the resource meta data from the base64 encoded data stream.

You can see how it works here:
http://regex101.com/r/eT7zN6